# Giving grayscale image color

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

[image: edited image after assignment statement]

I want to add color to a black and white image, I assume that changing the values of the pixels should work.

```py
for rows in rgb:
    for e in rows:
        for i in range(len(e)):
            max_val = e.max()
            min_val = e.min()
            if e[i] == max_val:
                e[i] * 2.5
            if e[i] == min_val:
                e[i] * 0.75
            else:
                e[i] * 1.5
```

the code doesnt return an error, but it also doesnt change the values. I want the numbers to be multiplied and reassigned by  the same array

Comment: You have no statements that assign new values to `e` (or to `e[i]`).  I would guess that the lines like `e[i] * 1.5` have no effect other than to print out the resulting value.

Comment: try something like `e[i] = e[i] * 2.5` for each of the statements

Comment: ok, so i've added the assignment statement and the values change. it changed the color of the image, but not in the way that I want

Comment: i just added the original image and the resulting image to my original question. pls anyone have a better suggestion on how to add colors to a black and white image?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually iterating through each pixel which has an inefficient `O(n^3)` run-time, we can take advantage of Numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) feature.

---

We first split the grayscale image into individual `BGR` channels using [`cv2.split()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#splitting-and-merging-image-channels). This will give us separate `B`, `G`, and `R` channels each with the same values. Next we multiply each channel with a scalar value using [`np.multiply()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html). Finally we combine each individual channel into a color image using [`cv2.merge()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge) to create a single multi-channel array

---

**Before**

[image]

```
>>> print(before.shape)
(331, 500, 3)
```

You might be wondering why the image has three channels even though it's obviously grayscale. Well it's because each channel has the same values ranging from `[0 ... 255]`

**After**

[image]

```
>>> print(after.shape)
(331, 500, 3)
```

Again, same number of channels, but we modified each individual channel

**TLDR:** To add color to a black and white image, we have to extract each individual `BGR` channel, modify each channel, then reconstruct the image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

before = cv2.imread('2.png')
b, g, r = cv2.split(before)

np.multiply(b, 1.5, out=b, casting="unsafe")
np.multiply(g, .75, out=g, casting="unsafe")
np.multiply(r, 1.25, out=r, casting="unsafe")

after = cv2.merge([b, g, r])

cv2.imshow('before', before)
cv2.imshow('after', after)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to apply a gradient color to a grayscale image.

```
Load the grayscale image

Convert it to 3 equal channels

Create a 1 pixel red image

Create a 1 pixel blue image

Concatenate the two

Resize linearly to 256 pixels as a Lookup Table (LUT)

Apply the LUT
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena_gray.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# convert to 3 equal channels
img = cv2.merge((img, img, img))

# create 1 pixel red image
red = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), np.uint8)
red[:] = (0,0,255)

# create 1 pixel blue image
blue = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), np.uint8)
blue[:] = (255,0,0)

# append the two images
lut = np.concatenate((red, blue), axis=0)

# resize lut to 256 values
lut = cv2.resize(lut, (1,256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# apply lut
result = cv2.LUT(img, lut)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_red_blue_lut_mapped.png', result)

# display result
cv2.imshow('RESULT', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Concatenate as many different colored pixels as you want to form a rainbow LUT, if desired.